# Running a terminal command from a C program in OS X

Tags: c, macos, pipe, system, popen

I'm trying to use plotutils to generate a plot from binary data. First, I wrote a   C program to export some sample binary data. Then, when I execute the following command in terminal, the plot gets generated as expected.

```
graph -T png -I d <'/Users/username/Documents/Restofpath/PlotutilsDataGen/testData'> '/Users/username/Documents/Restofpath/PlotutilsDataGen/testPlot.png'
```

But I want to combine this command with the C code that generates the binary data file so that once the code is executed, the plot is automatically exported. I tried two approaches: (i) using `popen()` which I suspect I'm doing incorrectly, and (ii) using `system()` which I thought should work, but doesn't. My entire code is as follows (I've listed both approaches together in the code by I naturally tried them individually):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int numSamples = 1024;
    double outputVec[2*numSamples];
    char outputPath[200] = "/Users/username/Documents/Restofpath/PlotutilsDataGen/testData";
    char plotcommand[400] = "graph -T png -I d <'/Users/username/Documents/Restofpath/PlotutilsDataGen/testData'> '/Users/username/Documents/Restofpath/PlotutilsDataGen/testPlot.png'";
    FILE *fp, *p;

    // Compute sample functions to export
    for(int ii = 0; ii < (2*numSamples); ii = ii + 2)
    {
        outputVec[ii] = (double)ii/2;
        outputVec[ii+1] = (double)(ii*2);
    }

    // Export as binary data file for plotutils to use for plotting
    fp = fopen(outputPath, "wb");
    fwrite(outputVec, sizeof(double), 2*numSamples, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    // Option 1
    p = popen(plotcommand, "w");
    pclose(p);

    // Option 2
    system(plotcommand);

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong or how I might get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: I think it might be related to the redirection. < / > is a shell thing, although I think system call's /bin/sh anyway.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the error I get is `sh: graph: command not found` on both occasions.

Comment: This has probably to do with an incorrect `PATH` setting when you run `system(plotcommand)`. `system()` runs in a (very simple) sh shell; interactively on the terminal, you are probably using bash, and in your .bashrc file, there are probably alterations to `PATH`, which are not used when running `sh` through `system()`. The easiest solution is to include the full path to `graph` in your `plotcommand` assignment. (But you may next end up with libraries not being found.)

Comment: Why not use GNU `libplot` to produce the plot straight from your code instead of relying on an external command?

Comment: Kind of a big omission. Then probably a path issue

Comment: @ZoffDino I'm looking to plot p(x) and q(x) against x on the same semi-log plot and I was under the impression that libplot didn't have a straightforward/elegant (not that what I propose is, but it may be simpler) way of doing this based on my skimming the collection of pl_****_r commands in the documentation. I thought I would have to manually draw axes, tick marks, etc. Am I missing something? If so, I apologize, and ask if you could you give me some hints? Thanks.

Comment: @Evert Providing the full path to `graph` worked perfectly. Thanks!